# Spring locale resolver - regex within .properties key

Tags: spring-mvc, properties-file

I want to use regex within my properties message key, like below

```
message.errorCode.^(\\5[0-9]{3})$ = Internal Error
```

but doing so throws an exception

```
javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: No message found under code 'message.errorCode.5000' for locale 'en'.
```

I want to avoid checking error code range before reading .properties label. Kindly suggest if there's a way to achieve so through regular expressions in .properties files.

Comment: why do you need to specify error code in property file?

Comment: [JavaDoc for Properties class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) gently suggests that it is not possible unless you code such a feature yourself.

Comment: before getting the property from property file just skip the error code.